# language C, TCP Server and Client

Tags: c, macos, tcp, server, client

I'm trying to create a tcpServer and tcpClient messages terminal. i run into a problem with some code i can't get to work

I Follow aftr this guide here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BIJGSQEipEE

```c
int newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, sizeof(newAddr));
printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntoa(newAddr.sin_port));
```

my error code is:

```
tcpServer.c:50:64: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'unsigned long' to parameter of type 'socklen_t *' (aka 'unsigned int *') [-Wint-conversion]
        newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, sizeof(newAddr));
                                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/sys/socket.h:686:73: note: passing argument to parameter here
int     accept(int, struct sockaddr * __restrict, socklen_t * __restrict)
                                                                        ^
tcpServer.c:54:81: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ntoa' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        printf("Connection accepted from %s:%d\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntoa(newAddr.sin_port));
```

Why does error 2 come arise?

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: The third argument of [POSIX `accept()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html) must be a "pointer to `socklen_t`". Your code is trying to pass a value of `size_t` type which is incompatible. Apparently the youtube guide you linked to has erroneous information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype of `accept` is like:

```
int accept(int socket, struct sockaddr *restrict address, socklen_t *restrict address_len);
```

(from the [Open Group Base Specification Issue 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/accept.html))

The `address_len` argument is a pointer to a `socklen_t` object, not a numerical length.

Instead, you should create a variable of type `socklen_t` to which you assign the size you're trying to pass:

```
socklen_t newAddrLength = sizeof(newAddr);
```

You can then pass a pointer to this variable in your call to `accept`:

```
newSocket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&newAddr, &newAddrLength);
```

---

I'm unsure what you are trying to do with `ntoa`. I believe the function that you'd want to use in its place is `ntohs`, which converts the network-order of the `sin_port` member to a host-order `uint16_t`:

```
ntohs(newAddr.sin_port))
```

You'll then want to either cast this to a standard integer type, or use the `PRIu16` format macro in `<inttypes.h>`:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

```
printf("Connection accepted from %s:%" PRIu16 "\n", inet_ntoa(newAddr.sin_addr), ntohs(newAddr.sin_port));
```